# How to show filename and line number in stacktrace in azure function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, stack-trace

**ATTENTION**: If anyone have even the slightest idea of how to accomplish this, please write an answer :)

How can I enable a feature such that filename and line number of each exception is captured in the stacktrace displayed in the azure function console window when debugging.
Or even better, how can I hit a debug breakpoint inside Visual Studio when debugging an azure function?

I have tried enabling debugging information = full, inside project settings -> build -> advanced -> debugging information = full, but this did not have any effect.

**Here is some code that will generate an index out of bounds exception which showcases the problem:**

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(test[0]);
```

**When I run the azure function in debug mode and hit the exception this is the generated output of the console window:**

```
[2020-10-02T13:01:38.289] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=180bf39f-1b60-401e-80a4-2073de926e9e, Duration=340ms)
[2020-10-02T13:01:38.290] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. System.Private.CoreLib: One or more errors occurred. (Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')). System.Private.CoreLib: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index').
```

Here is the Host.json file from the project:

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to use applicationInsight

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu I will use that when I deploy the code to azure, but I need to be able to develop locally and see this information when debugging :)

Comment: do you have startup config for logging? can you add it to the question?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu I have added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Did you publish your `.pdb` files? If you access your Function's web-space in Kudu do you see any `.pdb` files in the same directory as your `.dll` files?

Comment: @Dai I can see the filename and line in application insights when I investigate expectations and I have figured out that I need to enable different exceptions in Exception Settings window in Visual Studio. I am not sure specifically which one so I just enable every "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGcS.png

Answer (score 0):

you only enabled ApplicationInsight Logs.

add below lines into your config

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

then modify logging configuration like below

```
services.AddLogging(config =>
{
    // clear out default configuration ==> if necessary
    config.ClearProviders();

    config.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    config.AddDebug();
    
    if(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == EnvironmentName.Development) 
    {
        config.AddConsole();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have added the Logging lines to the host.json file and this resulted in a lot of debug output as expected but it still wont display the filename and line number of occuring exceptions.

The services.AddLogging() config does not exist in an azure function only in standard net core projects, so I cant enable this.

Answer (score 0):

I can now see the filename in Visual Studio debugger.
You need to enable different exceptions in Exception Settings window in Visual Studio. I am not sure specifically which one so I just enable every "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJGcS.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup the env variable CLI_DEBUG to 1 in your machine for seeing the filename and line number in the exceptions thrown.